# Creating monthly data and expanding data

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I have a data frame and I want to create an unbalanced panel based on the following dataset.

```
 profile<- c('lehman', 'john','oliver','stephen','picasso')
 start_date<-   c(2008-01-01, 2008-02-02,2008-04-02,2008-09-02,2009-02-02)
 end_date <-   c (2009-12-31, 2009-12-31, 2009-12-31,2009-12-31,2009-12-31)
 df<- data.frame(profile,start_date,end_date)
```

I would like to create two columns tid and myear. Myear is basically the month year starting from start date and it keeps expanding based on months till the last end date. Then I need a tid which is coded as 01 for myear 01-2008 and 02 for 02-2008 ....so on 12-2009 as 24. Can someone suggest how it can be done? Here is the expected output.

```
 profile      start_date    end_date     tid   myear
 lehman       2008-01-01    2009-12-31   01   01-2008
 lehman       2008-01-01    2009-12-31   02   02-2008
 ...          ..            ..           ..
 lehman       2008-01-01    2009-12-31   24   12-2009
 john         2008-02-02    2009-12-31   02   02-2008
 john         2008-02-02    2009-12-31   03   03-2008
 ..           ..             ..          ..
 john         2008-02-02    2009-12-31   24   12-2009
 ...          ..            ...          ..
 picasso      2009-02-02    2009-12-31   14   02-2009
 picasso      2009-03-02    2009-12-31   15   03-2009     
 ...          ...           ...          ..
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an idea. First make sure your dates are `as.Date` (i.e. `df[2:3] <- lapply(df[2:3], function(i) as.Date(i, format = '%Y-%m-%d'))`. Then create a list with the monthly sequence between start and end date. Count the lengths of that list and use them to expand your data frame. Add the sequence of dates as a new column and create `tid` based on each profile's length.

```
seq_lst <- lapply(Map(function(x, y) seq(x, y, by = 'months'), 
                      df$start_date, df$end_date), function(i) format(i, '%m-%Y'))

df <- df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), lengths(seq_lst)),]

df$myear <- unlist(seq_lst)

i1 <- setNames(seq(length(seq_lst[[1]])), seq_lst[[1]])
df$tid <- sprintf('%02d', i1[match(df$myear, names(i1))])

head(df)
#    profile start_date   end_date   myear tid
#1    lehman 2008-01-01 2009-12-31 01-2008  01
#1.1  lehman 2008-01-01 2009-12-31 02-2008  02
#1.2  lehman 2008-01-01 2009-12-31 03-2008  03
#1.3  lehman 2008-01-01 2009-12-31 04-2008  04
#1.4  lehman 2008-01-01 2009-12-31 05-2008  05
#1.5  lehman 2008-01-01 2009-12-31 06-2008  06
```

Comment: I am getting this error. Error in seq.default(x, y, by = "months") : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite. Any advise?

Comment: what should be the class of the profile? Mine is a list. Please suggest

Comment: great! it worked, the tid should be 1 for 2008-01 and for some columns if the start_date is 2008-02, i still get the first number to 1 instead of 2. Any advise how to get a right tid? for example see john profile in the output i have shown

Comment: yes it does, but it starts with the start date, for example if a person created his profile in 2008-01 then tid would be 1, (example lehman), on the other hand if the profile was created in 2008-02 then it should be 2.

Comment: I am getting this error. Error in seq.default(x, length.out = y) : 
  'from' cannot be NA, NaN or infinite

Comment: try adding `as.numeric` in front of `sub(...)` but for me it works as it is. Make sure again that your date variables are `as.Date`

Comment: it does work well for year 2008, but it starts with 2 for 2009-02, with tid as 02 instead of 14. Any advise?

Comment: sorry about that, may be we can add tid with 12 for start year with 2009, then we should be good to go,

Comment: yes i added the picasso rows in the question. please check

Comment: let me check your solution @ycw

Comment: @user3570187 Ok I think this should be it. Have a look

Answer (score 2):

Here is another possible way to achieve the task. I am following your sample data. For all names in `profile`, you have the same `end_date`, which is the 31st of December, 2009. The earliest `start_date` is the 1st of January, 2008. These two things are in my assumptions for the following code. So if your data is different from the sample data, the following would not be good.

I tried to create the sequences of dates using `do()`. Since I used `group_by()`, `start_date` and `end_date` were repeated in the accordance of the length of `myear`. Here, I created a sequence of dates by month and transformed the dates to the format you specified, namely year and month (e.g., 01-2008). `myear` is, hence, in character. Once, this job was done, I created `tid`. No matter what, the ending number is 24 for all levels in `profile`. So I did simple math. You want to know how many rows exist for each level of `profile`. Let's have a look of picasso. The start_date is Feb, 2009, which is the 14th month counting from Jan 2008. So you have 11 rows for picaso, which means n() = 11. Hence, (1 + (24 - 11)):24 creates a numeric sequence beginning at 14 and ending at 24. I leave a part of the output below of you.

```
library(dplyr)

group_by(df, profile) %>%
do(data.frame(start_date = .$start_date,
              end_date = .$end_date,
              myear = format(seq(from = .$start_date, to = .$end_date, by = "months"),
                             "%m-%Y")
             )
   ) %>%
mutate(tid = (1 + (24 - n())):24)

#69 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31 02-2009  14
#70 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31 03-2009  15
#71 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31 04-2009  16
#72 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31 05-2009  17
#73 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31 06-2009  18
#74 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31 07-2009  19
#75 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31 08-2009  20
#76 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31 09-2009  21
#77 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31 10-2009  22
#78 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31 11-2009  23
#79 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31 12-2009  24
```

DATA

```
structure(list(profile = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("john", 
"lehman", "oliver", "picasso", "stephen"), class = "factor"), 
start_date = structure(c(1199113200, 1201878000, 1207062000, 
1220281200, 1233500400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
end_date = structure(c(1262185200, 1262185200, 1262185200, 
1262185200, 1262185200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("profile", 
"start_date", "end_date"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution is based on functions from `tidyverse`, `lubridate`, and `stringr`.

#### Update

I misunderstood the definition of `tid`. Now the code should calculate `tid` as expected. `tid` shows the total number of records but the beginning of `tid` is the earliest month of the earliest year, while `myear` is month and year information combined together.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)    

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(start_date = ymd(start_date), end_date = ymd(end_date)) %>%
  mutate(start_year = year(start_date), end_year = year(end_date),
         start_month = month(start_date), end_month = month(end_date)) %>%
  mutate(Year = map2(start_year, end_year, `:`)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  group_by(profile) %>%
  mutate(first_year = ifelse(Year == min(Year), TRUE, FALSE),
         last_year = ifelse(Year == max(Year), TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(start_month = ifelse(!first_year, 1, start_month),
         end_month = ifelse(!last_year, 12, end_month)) %>%
  mutate(Month = map2(start_month, end_month, `:`)) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  mutate(endid = n() + Month - 1) %>%
  mutate(tid = first(Month):first(endid)) %>%
  mutate(Multiple_Year = ifelse(length(unique(Year)) > 1, TRUE, FALSE)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(tid = ifelse(Year > min(Year) & !Multiple_Year,
                      tid + 12 * (Year - min(Year)), tid)) %>%
  mutate(tid = str_pad(tid, width = 2, pad = "0")) %>%
  mutate(Month = str_pad(Month, width = 2, pad = "0")) %>%
  mutate(myear = paste(Month, Year, sep = "-")) %>%
  select(profile, start_date, end_date, tid, myear)
```

#### Output

Now examine part of the output `df2` to see if the code works as expected.

The first two rows of lehman

```
df2 %>%
  filter(profile %in% "lehman") %>%
  head(2)

    # A tibble: 2 x 5
  profile start_date   end_date   tid   myear
   <fctr>     <date>     <date> <chr>   <chr>
1  lehman 2008-01-01 2009-12-31    01 01-2008
2  lehman 2008-01-01 2009-12-31    02 02-2008
```

The last one row of lehman

```
df2 %>%
  filter(profile %in% "lehman") %>%
  tail(1)

# A tibble: 1 x 5
  profile start_date   end_date   tid   myear
   <fctr>     <date>     <date> <chr>   <chr>
1  lehman 2008-01-01 2009-12-31    24 12-2009
```

The first two rows of picasso

```
df2 %>% 
  filter(profile %in% "picasso") %>% 
  head(2)  

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  profile start_date   end_date   tid   myear
   <fctr>     <date>     <date> <chr>   <chr>
1 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31    14 02-2009
2 picasso 2009-02-02 2009-12-31    15 03-2009
```

#### Data Preparation

```
profile <- c('lehman', 'john','oliver','stephen','picasso')
start_date <- c("2008-01-01", "2008-02-02", "2008-04-02", "2008-09-02", "2009-02-02")
end_date <- c("2009-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2009-12-31", "2009-12-31")
df <- data.frame(profile,start_date,end_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you have accepted an answer, but for completeness, a `data.table` method works as well:

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt.l <- setDT(dt)[ , list(myear = seq(start_date, end_date, by = "1 month"), by = profile]
dt.l <- dt.l[ ,tid := ifelse(as.numeric(year(myear)) > 2008, as.numeric(month(myear)) + 12, as.numeric(month(myear)))]
dt.l <- setDT(dt.l)[, myear := format(as.Date(myear), "%Y-%m")]
```