Determine current state by month
I have a challenging question. I have the table as below, with open date, closed date, and status...

My goal is to show a count of items that remain open during each month and create a graph like below:

So far the best approach I can think of is to subtract the closed date from the start date and create a matrix with a value of 1 for each month in between (screenshot below). BUT I can't figure out how to do it. Can anyone guide me here? or recommend a better solution?


library(tidyverse); df |> mutate(across(Open:Closed, ~lubridate::mdy())) |> pivot_longer(Open:Closed) |> mutate(chg = if_else(name == "Open", 1, if_else(Status == "Closed", -1, 0))) |> arrange(value) |> mutate(active = cumsum(chg)) then it's a question of defining whether the monthly number you want is the max number active during the month, the total unique number active during the month, the number active at the end of the month, etc.

It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please do not post code or data in images

Maybe checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44522871/creating-monthly-data-and-expanding-data

I went with this
library(tidyverse)

(init_df <- tribble(
  ~Open, ~Closed, ~Status,
  "012024", "052024", "Closed",
  "112023", "032024", "Closed",
  "022024", "022024", "Closed",
  "022024", "011900", "Open"
) |>
  mutate(across(
    Open:Closed,
    lubridate::my
  ),
  # rather than a date in the past
  # something still open should have a date
  # far into the future
  Closed = case_match(Status,
    "Open" ~ dmy("31129999"),
    .default = Closed
  )
  ) |>
  select(-Status))


(month_to_count <- 
    seq.Date(min(init_df$Open),
            to = max(as.Date(setdiff(init_df$Closed,
                                     dmy("31129999"))), 
                     na.rm = TRUE),
            by = "1 month"
            )  |> 
    enframe(value = "month", name = "num")
  )


(final_counts <- month_to_count |>
  left_join(init_df,
    by = join_by(between(
      month,
      Open, Closed
    ))) |>
  reframe(
    n = n(),
    .by = c(num, month)
  ))

